# SQL Error[42601]: Error: syntax error at or near "0"

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dblink

I can't understand how ti make an array from select and I have an error

> SQL Error[42601]: Error: syntax error at or near "0"", Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute query.

```
create temporary table house_address as
   (SELECT full_address
    FROM dblink('db_d',
         'drop table if exists _x17092018;
             create temporary table _x17092018 (
             guid character varying,
             full_address character varying,
             address_guid character varying
          ); 
          do $$
             declare
                guids_list character varying[]
                   := ''{(''' ||
                      (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT guid, ''', ''')
                       FROM lc) ||
                      ''')}'';
                r character varying;
             begin
                foreach r in array guids_list 
                loop
                   insert into _x17092018
                      select r, t.*
                      FROM sm.func_by_houseid(r, TRUE, ''db'') as t;
                end loop;
             END$$;'
         ) AS addr(full_address TEXT)
   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error must come from the initialization of `guids_list`.

The way it is written, it will come out as something like

```
{[guid1', 'guid ' containing spaces and quote', 'guid3]}
```

which is clearly not what you intend. Besides, as I tried to demonstrate, it is open to SQL injection.

You could use something like

```
'guids_list character varying[] := ' ||
   (SELECT quote_literal(array_agg(DISTINCT guid)) FROM lc) || ';'
```